# Core data to-many NSPredicate with AND

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nspredicate

I'm trying to write a query for the find-as-you-type search bar. What I want to do is query "Kind", and return any Kinds for which there is a LocalName with ('name' LIKE %@ AND localeIdentifier == %@).

If I'm only searching the names (so ignoring the localeIdentifier), I could do something like this:

```
ANY localized.name LIKE %@
```

What I want is something more like

```
ANY localized.(name LIKE %@ AND localeIdentifier == %@)
```

To sum up, searching "Kind", any one item in the to-many relationship "localized" should match both name and localeIdentifier.

Any ideas for the correct syntax of this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want is a [subquery](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionForSubquery:usingIteratorVariable:predicate:). In predicate format syntax:

```
SUBQUERY(self.localized, $x, $x.name LIKE %@ AND $x.localeIdentifier == %@).@count > 0
```

where the `SUBQUERY` expression returns a collection of instances in the `self.localized` collection that match the predicate in the third argument. `Kind` instances for which this SUBQUERY expression is non-empty (ie `@count > 0`) match your desired criteria.

The SUBQUERY expression was introduced in OS X 10.5.

Comment: Great hint! Exactly what I needed!