# Core Data with multiple to Many Predicates

Tags: iphone, cocoa, core-data, nspredicate

For a relationship like this:

TagGroups<---->>Tags<<---->>Object

An Object has tags, tags can be grouped by tagGroups.

I have an object, and I want to know all of the TagGroups its Tags belong to.

To construct he predicate, I first tried the following format string:

(SELF is a TagGroup)

```
NSPredicate* p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN SELF.tags.objects" , object];
```

This fails because sets are not traversed ala Key-ValueCoding.

After some research I have found several questions explaining SUBQUERY

[Core Data, try to use NSPredicate to filter a toMany relationship set but get the "to-many key not allowed here" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644849/core-data-try-to-use-nspredicate-to-filter-a-tomany-relationship-set-but-get-the)

[Core data to-many NSPredicate with AND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344184/core-data-to-many-nspredicate-with-and)

These seem to be part of the solution, but unlike these questions I am not testing for a value like "tag.name", but membership within the collection.

So with that in mind I tried this:

```
NSPredicate* p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN SUBQUERY(SELF.tags, $eachTag,$eachTag.object)" , object];
```

Which fails to parse (I tried a few other variants unsuccessfully as well)

Any ideas on how to construct this format string properly?

Update:

Also tried it from the other direction:

```
NSPredicate* p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ALL SUBQUERY(%@.tags,$eachTag,$eachTag.tagGroup)" , anObject];
```

Comment: I'd be very surprised if CoreData could translate `SUBQUERY` expressions into a SQL statement.  I could be wrong, though.

Comment: I wasn't aware of it until I started digging up info on fetching many-to-many relationships using NSFR.

Answer (score 0):

If you "have an object" i.e. you have a particular managedObject whose entity is `Object` then you don't need a predicate. You just need to walk the relationship keypath.

Here is an example implemented with dictionaries by it works the same way with a managed object.

```
NSDictionary *tagGroup1=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"tagGroupOne",@"name",@"tagGroup1",@"theValue",nil];
NSDictionary *tagGroup2=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"tagGroupTwo",@"name",@"tagGroup2",@"theValue",nil];
NSDictionary *tag1=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:tagGroup1 forKey:@"tagGroup"];
NSDictionary *tag2=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:tagGroup2 forKey:@"tagGroup"];

NSSet *tags=[NSSet setWithObjects:tag1,tag2,nil];

NSDictionary *objD=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:tags,@"tags",nil];
NSLog(@"tagGroup names=%@",[objD valueForKeyPath:@"tags.tagGroup.name"]);
NSLog(@"tagGroup objects=%@",[objD valueForKeyPath:@"tags.tagGroup"]);
```

... which outputs:

```
tagGroup names={(
    tagGroupTwo,
    tagGroupOne
)}

tagGroup objects={(
        {
        name = tagGroupTwo;
        theValue = tagGroup2;
    },
        {
        name = tagGroupOne;
        theValue = tagGroup1;
    }
)}
```

So, really all you need is a line like:

```
NSSet *tagGroups=[anInstanceOfObject valueForKeyPath:@"tags.tagGroup"];
```

That's the power of key-value coding.

You would only need a subquery if you were trying to fetch `Objects` that had a relationship to a `TagGroup` with a particular attribute value.

Comment: Thanks, the issue is I am trying to construct an NSFetchRequest to be used by an NSFetchedResultsController. I am tying to do that so I don't have to fault all of the intermediate objects into memory and so that I can rely on NSFRC to handle batching the results. In the end, I ended up with a solution like yours, but it isn't ideal. There should be a way to properly construct the SUBQUERY to get the results